# Autocomplete with Google Places API

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

I am developing an application related to train. How can I autocomplete textview with Railway Station name in India using Google Places API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The railway station names are static and are not huge in number, so you can put them in JavaScript array as well. That would be faster as well to autocomplete.